# Go, Dijkstra : print out the path, not just calculate the shortest distance

Tags: algorithm, graph, go, dijkstra, shortest-path

Go, Dijkstra : print out the path, not just calculate the shortest distance.

http://play.golang.org/p/A2jnzKcbWD

I was able to find the shortest distance using Dijkstra algorithm, maybe not.
The code can be found here.

But it would be useless if I can't print out the path.
With a lot of pointers going on, I can't figure out how to print out the final path that takes the least amount of weights.

In short, how do I not only find the shortest distance, but also print out the shortest path on this given code?

The link is here:

http://play.golang.org/p/A2jnzKcbWD

And the snippet of the code is below:

```
const MAXWEIGHT = 1000000

type MinDistanceFromSource map[*Vertex]int

func (G *Graph) Dijks(StartSource, TargetSource *Vertex) MinDistanceFromSource {
  D := make(MinDistanceFromSource)
  for _, vertex := range G.VertexArray {
    D[vertex] = MAXWEIGHT
  }
  D[StartSource] = 0

  for edge := range StartSource.GetAdEdg() {
    D[edge.Destination] = edge.Weight
  }
  CalculateD(StartSource, TargetSource, D)
  return D
}

func CalculateD(StartSource, TargetSource *Vertex, D MinDistanceFromSource) {
  for edge := range StartSource.GetAdEdg() {
    if D[edge.Destination] > D[edge.Source]+edge.Weight {
      D[edge.Destination] = D[edge.Source] + edge.Weight
    } else if D[edge.Destination] < D[edge.Source]+edge.Weight {
      continue
    }
    CalculateD(edge.Destination, TargetSource, D)
  }
}
```

I did something with array to see what is being updated.

http://play.golang.org/p/bRXYjnIGxy

This gives ms

```
   [A->D D->E E->F F->T B->E E->D E->F F->T]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you adjust the new path distance here

```
   if D[edge.Destination] > D[edge.Source]+edge.Weight {
      D[edge.Destination] = D[edge.Source] + edge.Weight
```

Set some array element (say, `P` for "parent") to point that you have come to `Destination` from `Source`.

```
P[edge.Destination] = edge.Source
```

After the algorithm ends, in this array each vertex will have its predecessor on the path leading from the starting vertex.

PS. OK, not with arrays and indices ...

Add a new field `Prev` to the Vertex:

```
type Vertex struct {
    Id      string
    Visited bool
    AdjEdge []*Edge
    Prev *Vertex
}
```

When adjusting distance:

```
if D[edge.Destination] > D[edge.Source]+edge.Weight {
    D[edge.Destination] = D[edge.Source] + edge.Weight
    edge.Destination.Prev = edge.Source
```

And when you display the results:

```
for vertex1, distance1 := range distmap1 {
    fmt.Println(vertex1.Id, "=", distance1)
    if vertex1.Prev != nil {
        fmt.Println (vertex1.Id, " -> ", vertex1.Prev.Id)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? What do you mean by Set some array element? With what should I initialize the array? And P is an array then how can the index be the Vertex type? Thanks!@

Comment: Check the answer, I corrected it a bit. You initialize the array with some invalid vertex index.

Comment: Hm is this what you talking about ? http://play.golang.org/p/TOlvZUwO5y This gives me non-integer slice index edge.Destination

Comment: I did similar thing, but still can't combine these results http://play.golang.org/p/bRXYjnIGxy

Answer (score 0):

Shortest Path-Printing using Dijkstra's Algorithm for Graph (Here it is implemented for undirected Graph. The following code prints the shortest distance from the source_node to all the other nodes in the graph.

> > **It also prints the shortest path from the source node to the node requested by the user.**
> >     Suppose,you need to find the shortest path from **A** to **B** in the graph. Then input **A** as the source node and **B** as the destination node.

**Code**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define INF (unsigned)!((int)0)

const int MAX=2e4;
vector<pair<int,int>> graph[MAX];

bool visit[MAX];
int dist[MAX];

multiset<pair<int,int>> s;
int parent[MAX];                                 // used to print the path

int main(){
    memset(visit,false,sizeof(visit));
    memset(dist,INF,sizeof(dist));
    memset(parent,-1,sizeof(parent));

    int nodes,edges;        cin>>nodes>>edges;
    for(auto i=0;i<edges;++i){
        int a,b,w;
        cin>>a>>b>>w;
        graph[a].push_back(make_pair(b,w));
        graph[b].push_back(make_pair(a,w));   //Comment it to make the Directed Graph
    }
    int source_node;    cin>>source_node;
    dist[source_node]=0;
    s.insert(make_pair(0,source_node));

    while(!s.empty()){
        pair<int,int> elem=*s.begin();
        s.erase(s.begin());
        int node=elem.second;
        if(visit[node])continue;
        visit[node]=true;
        for(auto i=0;i<graph[node].size();++i){
            int dest=graph[node][i].first;
            int w=graph[node][i].second;
            if(dist[node]+w<dist[dest]){
                dist[dest]=dist[node]+w;
                parent[dest]=node;
                s.insert(make_pair(dist[dest],dest));
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"NODE"<<"         "<<"DISTANCE"<<endl;
    for(auto i=1;i<=nodes;++i){
        cout<<i<<"         "<<dist[i]<<endl;
    }
    /*----PRINT SHORTEST PATH FROM THE SOURCE NODE TO THE NODE REQUESTED-------*/
    int node_for_path;      cin>>node_for_path;
    int dest_node=node_for_path;
    stack<int> path;
    while(parent[node_for_path]!=source_node){
        path.push(node_for_path);
        node_for_path=parent[node_for_path];
    }
    path.push(node_for_path);
    path.push(source_node);
    cout<<"Shortest Path from "<<source_node<<"to "<<dest_node<<":"<<endl;
    while(!path.empty()){
        if(path.size()==1) cout<<path.top();
        else cout<<path.top()<<"->";
        path.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
/*TEST CASE*/
9 14        //---NODES,EDGES---
1 2 4       //---START,END,WEIGHT---FOR THE NO OF EDGES
2 3 8
3 4 7
4 5 9
5 6 10
6 7 2
7 8 1
8 1 8
2 8 11
8 9 7
9 7 6
9 3 2
6 3 4
4 6 14
1           //---SOURCE_NODE
5           //-----NODE TO WHICH PATH IS REQUIRED
---END---*/
```

hope it helps